# IF EXISTS Alternatives in SQL Server CE Or SQLite

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, sql-server-ce

I've got some legacy SQL statements in the following form:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ... WHERE ...)
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ... WHERE ...)
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ... WHERE ...)
INSERT INTO ...
```

Is there a way to change this query to make it work in both SQL Server CE and/or SQLite and normal SQL Server? Note that moving the procedural IF logic out of the SQL is not an option.

Thanks.

Comment: Using joins would be possible. But without a real example there not much more to tell.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting the conditions in the `insert` itself?  You need to use `insert . . . select`, if you are using a values statement.

```
insert into table(col1, . . . coln)
    select val1, . . . valn
    where EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ... WHERE ...) AND
          NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ... WHERE ...) AND
          EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ... WHERE ...);
```

I'm not 100% sure this will work with both databases without a `from` clause.  In case you don't have one, you can do:

```
insert into table(col1, . . . coln)
    select *
    from (select val1, . . . valn) t
    where EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ... WHERE ...) AND
          NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ... WHERE ...) AND
          EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ... WHERE ...);
```